# Array for valid knight moves in chess (C)

Tags: c

for my college project I was asked to write the function: chessPosArray*** validKnightMoves().
The question specifies the function should return a two dimensional dynamic array of pointers to arrays of the possible positions the knight can land on from each starting position on the board.

when I attempt to print what is in the array the program doesn't print anything and exits with code -1073741819

Here is the Code:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef char chessPos[2];

typedef struct _chessPosArray 
{
    unsigned int size;
    chessPos* positions;
} chessPosArray;

chessPosArray*** validKnightMoves();
void checkKnightMoves(chessPosArray*** arrptr, int row, int col);

int main() 
{
    chessPosArray ***arr = validKnightMoves();

    printf("%d\n", arr[3][3]->size);

    return 0;
}

chessPosArray*** validKnightMoves() 
{
    /// To make a two dimensional dynamic array we will make an array for the rows - each row will point to an array of columns
    chessPosArray*** arr = malloc(sizeof(**arr) * 8);
    if (arr == NULL)
    {
        printf("allocation falliure");
        exit(1);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++) //each column will have a pointer to a pointer 
    {
        arr[i] = (chessPosArray**)malloc(sizeof(*arr) * 8);
        if (arr[i] == NULL)
        {
            printf("allocation falliure");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) //here we will check each space on the board too see where the knight can move from it (using a function)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 8; j++) 
        {
            checkKnightMoves(arr, i, j);
        }
    }
    
    return arr;
}

void checkKnightMoves (chessPosArray *** arrptr, int row, int col) //This function will check all possible movments for the knight
{
    int newx, newy;
    int counter = 0;
    int physicalsize = 1;

    int dx[8] = { 2, 2, 1, 1, -1, -1, -2, -2 };
    int dy[8] = { 1, -1, 2, -2, 2, -2, 1, -1 };
    
    arrptr[row][col]->positions = (chessPos*)malloc(sizeof(chessPos));
    if (arrptr[row][col]->positions == NULL)
    {
        printf("allocation falliure");
        exit(1);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++) 
    {
        newx = row + dx[i];
        newy = col + dy[i];

        if(newx > 0 && newy > 0 && newx <= 8 && newy <= 8) 
        {
            if(counter > physicalsize) 
            {
                realloc(arrptr[row][col]->positions, sizeof(chessPos) * 2);
                if (arrptr[row][col]->positions == NULL)
                {
                    printf("reallocation faliure");
                    exit(1);
                }
                physicalsize *= 2;
            }
            
            sprintf(arrptr[row][col]->positions[counter], "%c%c", newx+'A'-1, newy + '0');
            counter++;
        }
    }

    arrptr[row][col]->size = counter;
}
```

My main should have printed the number 8 as this is the amount of valid moves the knight can take from that position but it did not print anything.

Comment: Please post the code as a complete code section that can be compiled as-is.

Comment: @WeatherVane Edited the post to have all the code in one complete section

Comment: Your `realloc` call is sketchy. You're always allocating space for only two moves, regardless of what value `counter` holds.

Comment: Triple star programming is legal but ugly (and error prone). Did the assignment _require_ the `chessPosArray*** validKnightMoves()` prototype??? Also, this is an old-style K&R prototype and the modern (since the 1990s) ANSI version would be `chessPosArray ***validKnightMoves(void)`. If so, I'm beginning to question the quality of the instructor ...

Comment: Unrelated, but `newx <= 8 && newy <= 8` is _too_ inclusive. The value 8 is not a valid position.

Comment: Thank you I wanted to see if it compiles cleanly (it did).

Comment: @CraigEstey Yes it's the required prototype

Comment: @paddy you're right, I meant to increase the size by 2 every time, so it should have been `realloc(arrptr[row][col]->positions, physicalsize * sizeof(chessPos) * 2);`

Comment: Yeah, but also still wrong. See my answer.

Comment: [Should I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/should-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) Also: [Three Star Programmer](https://wiki.c2.com/?ThreeStarProgrammer)

Answer (score 2):

There may be other issues, but this one is *definitely* incorrect:

```
if(counter > physicalsize) 
{
    realloc(arrptr[row][col]->positions, sizeof(chessPos) * 2);
    if (arrptr[row][col]->positions == NULL)
    {
        printf("reallocation failure");
        exit(1);
    }
    physicalsize *= 2;
}
```

Two problems there:

1. You always `realloc` storage for only two `chessPos` values. It appears that what you were actually trying to do is double the size of the storage.
2. You don't store the returned pointer. `realloc` can actually move your data to a new memory location. It returns a pointer to the start of the reallocated memory, which may or may not be the same pointer.

So, this should be something like:

```
if(counter > physicalsize) 
{
    int newsize = physicalsize * 2;
    chessPos* positions = arrptr[row][col]->positions;
    positions = realloc(positions, sizeof(chessPos) * newsize);
    if (positions == NULL)
    {
        printf("reallocation faliure");
        exit(1);
    }
    arrptr[row][col]->positions = positions;
    physicalsize = newsize;
}
```

On an unrelated note, the 'valid' test before this is checking `newx <= 8 && newy <= 8` which is incorrect. The value 8 is not a valid position. You should test `newx < 8 && newy < 8`.

---

But you're not out of the woods yet. This 3-star-programmer approach is muddying the waters and you actually failed to allocate storage for your `chessPos` objects at all. What you've done is allocate 8 rows of 8 columns of uninitialized pointers.

If you run the program in a debugger, you'll find that it crashes on this call:

```
arrptr[row][col]->positions = malloc(sizeof(chessPos));
```

Why? Well, when you dereference `arrptr[row][col]` to access the `positions` field, you're following a pointer into the unknown and anything can happen.

I recommend you simplify your program to store your data as a `chessPosArray**` instead. The allocation looks like this:

```
chessPosArray** validKnightMoves() 
{
    chessPosArray** arr = malloc(sizeof(*arr) * 8);
    if (arr == NULL)
    {
        printf("allocation falliure");
        exit(1);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = (chessPosArray*)malloc(sizeof(*arr[i]) * 8);
        if (arr[i] == NULL)
        {
            printf("allocation falliure");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 8; j++) 
        {
            checkKnightMoves(arr, i, j);
        }
    }
    
    return arr;
}
```

And then you make the appropriate changes to `checkKnightMoves`. That means accessing fields via the `.` operator instead of `->`. *e.g.*

```
arrptr[row][col].positions = malloc(sizeof(chessPos));
```

And so on...

---

But, you're STILL not out of the woods!

This right here has a buffer overflow:

```
sprintf(arrptr[row][col].positions[counter], "%c%c", newx+'A'-1, newy + '0');
```

Why? Because `sprintf` writes a null-terminated string. Your data type only has storage for 2 characters, but this call writes 3. There's no need to use `sprintf` at all here. Instead, just:

```
chessPos* pos = &arrptr[row][col].positions[counter];
pos[0] = newx + 'A';
pos[1] = newy + '0';
```

But now, *don't* expect that to be a string you can pass via `%s` in a `printf` call. It's not null-terminated. Perhaps what you *actually* wanted was to use `sprintf` but make your data type large enough:

```
typedef char chessPos[3];
```

---

Is that all? Maybe. You do still have memory leaks, because your program doesn't clean up. At least it doesn't crash.

You should debug further. Note that I picked up all these issues by just turning on GCC's address sanitizer with `-fsanitize=address`. It's a very useful tool. I also recommend enabling all warnings with `-Wall`.